# Updates to SQL Azure reverting when closing browser or waiting 1 minute

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, sqlclient

I have a tricky issue with an update query in SQL Azure.  I have tried using an EntityFramework update, to include attaching to the entity, setting it to Modified state, and calling SaveChanges on the context.  I have also done a direct SQL Update statement using System.Data.SQLClient.

In both cases, if I'm viewing the database in Visual Studio through the SQL Server Object Explorer, the change is applied immediately, at first.  If I close the browser where I initiated the update from (via an call to a ASP.NET MVC Controller, or if I just wait for about a minute and do nothing, the database reverts the updated record to it's original values.  If I do 4 or 5 updates all in a row, typically the last one in the sequence exhibits this behavior, where the first 3 or 4 "stick".

Please help.  I'm at my wits end with this!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using transactions in your code? Or can an earlier request that arrives later overwrite the changes made by later requests that were processed earlier?

Comment: I tried putting it into a transaction because I read an article that seemed to suggest it.  No difference in behavior.  In this case, I can assure you that multiple requests are not being fired at once (it's a closed system at the moment)

Comment: Are there triggers defined? Are there other processes updating this database?

Comment: I was thinking based on some reading that there might be triggers that were defined on the database, but I didn't configure them myself, so perhaps it was the out-of-the-box behavior of the Azure SQL service?  There could very well be other processes updating this database from elsewhere.  I have some scheduled WebJobs that do database updates, but I don't think that they touch this same entity.

Comment: It is possible that your transaction didn't commit. Try not using transactions and let us know what happens.